# Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo:

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS. Currently, I'm using ROS kinetic on raspberry pi 3, ubuntu mate.I've also installed urg-node with `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-urg-node` I'm trying to use Hokuyo sensor, UTM-30LX, connected to my raspberry pi 3 through USB port. However, after running the command: `rosrun urg_node urg_node` , I got the following output:

---

[ERROR] [1522135176.872087477]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo:
/dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200
could not open serial device.

---

Also, when I'm trying to get the ID of Hokuyo sensor with the command: `rosrun urg_node getID /dev/ttyACM0` , I got a similar output:

---

getID failed: Could not open serial Hokuyo:
/dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200
could not open serial device.

---

Am I suppose to run any command beforehand or set any configuration?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286646/error-connecting-to-hokuyo:-could-not-open-serial-hokuyo:/) by [DesmondTan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34324/desmondtan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably you don't have the rights to open the port.
You can easily check with the following command `od /dev/ttyACM0`. If this does not work, but works with `sudo od /dev/ttyACM0`, this is the reason.

You need to add yourself to the `dialout` group: `sudo adduser <YOUR_USERNAME> dialout`, log out and log back in. Check if you really are in the `dialout` group by checking the output of `groups`. This should get you access.

Please report back if this does not solve the issues, preferably with any additional details.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Justin-RR2-IP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36487/justin-rr2-ip/) on 2018-07-17**:
I encountered exactly the same issue as Desmond and following the above answer I was able to resolve the issue.

However, after creating a master machine and ssh'ing into the drone with the Hokuyo, the issue has returned. Any idea how to resolve it this time?

**Comment by [Justin-RR2-IP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36487/justin-rr2-ip/) on 2018-07-18**:
I am unable to run the command `od /dev/ttyAMC0` or `sudo od /dev/ttyAMC0`

I get the output:

od: dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory

**Comment by [kyleGao](https://answers.ros.org/users/37513/kylegao/) on 2018-09-14**:
I also encountered the same issue. `od/dev/ttyACM0` gives me `od: /dev/ttyACM0: Device or resource busy` while `sudo od /dev/ttyACM0` works and is able to got data from my Hokuyo. I added the user to dialout as @mgruhler said, but after logging back in, I still run into this problem. Any ideas?

**Comment by [kyleGao](https://answers.ros.org/users/37513/kylegao/) on 2018-09-14**:
Up date: `od /dev/ttyACM0` is working now after I reboot the computer. But when I `rosrun urg_node urg_node` I still got errors:

```
Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo: /dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200 no response.
```

**Comment by [Justin-RR2-IP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36487/justin-rr2-ip/) on 2018-09-15**:
Not sure if this will help but it turned out my issue was a timing issue, with the drone's clock being reset to Feb 2016 after every reboot.  We fixed the timing issue by making the PC an NTP server and syncing the drone's time from it.  After doing this, we stopped getting the error

**Comment by [kyleGao](https://answers.ros.org/users/37513/kylegao/) on 2018-09-18**:
Thank you @Justan-RR2-IP the time is not an issue in my case. Still suffering from this.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-04-05**:
is your issue resolved or persists?

**Comment by [Himanshu Mandhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/81486/himanshu-mandhan/) on 2021-08-21**:
I am also getting the same issue after using the command **od /dev/ttyACM0** as no such file or directory. If anyone get the solution kindly share it

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-21**:
which distro are you using?